# Can't customise tab bar in iOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I have a tab in iOS 5 and wish to have a image for the `TabBarButton` for the selected and on not-selected states. Here is the code:

```
 BOOL isIOS5 = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.0;

    if(isIOS5)
    {
        //[tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab-bg"]];
       // [tabBarController.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cell-bg"]];

         [[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list-menu-selected"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list-menu"]];
        [[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gallery-menu-selected"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gallery-menu"]];
        [[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map-menu-selected"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map-menu"]];
        [[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"submit-menu-selected"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"submit-menu"]];
        [[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search-menu-selected"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search-menu"]];
    }
```

i.e. the images are 44px height for non-retina display so they should be enough to fill the space

The problem is that the images dont't go from top to bottom: there remains some space not filled at the bottom of the tabbar. Has anyone ever had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's 49, as you can see here:
http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're already checking for specific cases like iOS 5, might be easiest just to create images that match the exact pixel height of the bar already. Alternatively you can look at what properties you can set on the tabBar.item itself.

Comment: isn't 44px the height of the tab bar?

Comment: I think it actually varies according to what version it is (at least I recall that, from somewhere). You may be able to get the properties by asking the item for its bounds/frame.